# default boot device missing or boot failed after destroying GPT data

Tags: boot, partition, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 parallel to Windows 10. I was unable to find any of the partions while installing ubuntu and I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/443535) answer. I tried the steps mentioned by Walid Ammou. I then wanted to make sure nothing went wrong so I quit the ubuntu installation without installing and rebooted my system but I am not able to boot into Windows. I get a message saying `default boot device missing or boot failed`. My hard drive doesn't seem to be in the boot menu.

I will appreciate any help!

**EDIT:**
[This is the output of `sudo parted -l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYOn.jpg)

**EDIT2**
[This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzhFz.jpg)

**EDIT 3:**
[This is the output of `gdsik`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhray.jpg)

Comment: Your fdisk program is too old to understand the GPT partitioning scheme. The disk contains a "protective MBR" for the sole purpose of warning that the disk is partitioned. The partition in the MBR spans the whole disk, and has nothing to do with the real GPT partitions, which fdisk is unable to handle. Use a better program like gdisk, or a newer version of fdisk. See Rod Smith's [excellent webpages](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html) for more information.

Comment: @JohanMyréen please see the edit